# using `map` to construct multiple named tuples

Tags: python

Suppose I have a namedtuple like

```
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point','x y')
```

Why is it that I construct a single object via

```
>>> Point(3,4)
```

yet when I want to apply Point via map, I have to call

```
>>> map(Point._make,[(3,4),(5,6)])
```

I suspect this has something to do with classmethods, perhaps, and am hoping that in figuring this out I'll learn more about them as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Point._make` takes a tuple as its sole argument. Your `map` call is equivalent to `[Point._make((3, 4)), Point._make((5, 6))]`.

Using a list comprehension makes this more obvious: `[Point(*t) for t in [(3, 4), (5, 6)]]` achieves the same effect.

Comment: You can also use starmap from itertools - list(starmap(Point, [[1,2], [3, 4]]))

Comment: There's a dozen other ways to do it, but a list comprehension is the clearest in what it does exactly.